# Need help about SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new android deverlopment. I have a question about SQLite database 
In my application, I used eclipse and created 1 database called "game" then I use "Questoid SQLite manager" plugin to open this database. But I see, the database doesn't has .db extension. so i cant open it in Questoid SQLite manager (there are 3 file in this database folder: 'webview.db, webviewCache.da' and 'game' (not game.db) and i can only open 2 first file). Why, please help me!
thank!

Comment: Obvious: why not name your db "game.db" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the free SQLite Database Browser from http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/. It will be able to access it without the extension, or with .db. .sqlite etc.

Comment: i have it already! but I cant find out the path of data folder. It's in Android sdk folder? right?

Comment: You can use DDMS in eclipse to pull the DB from the app and put it on your desktop. If you don't see DDMS, just click `window` in the toolbar up top, then choose `Open Perspective` then `other` then click DDMS

Comment: But,are there other way to change it to game.db? so I can see it directly in Eclipse whenever I updated database and dont need spent so much time to Pull all data. Thank again ^^!

Comment: if you use something like `private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "name";` just change it to `private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "name.db";`